# IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL BSOD after installing wifi card in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bsod, wifi-driver

I have just built my first computer:

i5-3570K
MSI Z77A-G41
16GB 1600Mhz RAM
128GB SSD & 500GB HDD
MSI 7770GHz GDDR5 video card

I installed windows 8 fine onto the SSD. I then put in the WiFi card I got, TP-LINK (TL-WDN4800) in to connect to the internet and download drivers for all my hardware that I just put together. I boot up windows it asks for the WEP key to connect to the wifi. I give it, then it asks for a login; I don't have one. So i think I must have to install the included drivers first. Do that, asks to restart, BSOD (IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL).

SO I plan on reinstalling windows 8 because safe mode won't work, it goes straight to the BSOD when booting. Once I do that I'll get more up to date drivers I guess, but my question is what do I put into the login info for the wifi? I tried admin:password and it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the card...there may be something *wrong* with it.  Anyway, there's no way for us to know what credentials your wireless is configured with, you need to talk to whomever set it up.

Comment: It's my dad's wifi, no credentials. I just logged in with my laptop with windows 7, didn't ask for a password. I remove the card, I have no way of connecting to the internet...

Comment: If you remove the card and problems clear up (ie, it's defective) you'll be replacing it anyway.  And if it's defective you won't be using it *anyway*.  And if no credentials are necessary you shouldn't need a login:password - those *are* credentials.

Comment: @Ben, your question is not clear. The post reads as if you want to know about the BSOD error, but it turns out you just want to know the default username/password for the router. I suggest (otherwise your post will be closed), you edit the question and make it about the default username and password, then add another question about the BSOD  :)

Answer (score 0):

The default username and password are both admin

[Source](http://defaultpasswordslist.com/vendor/tp_link)